# CakePHP Pagination with HTML Entities not working

Tags: cakephp, pagination, html-entities

Could anyone riddle me this.

The following code produces this-> http://www.evernote.com/shard/s29/sh/87fce2c2-c323-461b-a5ac-1ccc6d2ba3ad/32b87ce0602a33dfda59c4b9e69be54b

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev("&lsaquo;", array('escape' => false), null, array('class' => 'pagination_disabled')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '')); ?>    
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next("&rsaquo;", array('escape' => false), null, array('class' => 'pagination_disabled')); ?>
```

I have cleared the cache and tried replacing the `prev` with an entity number and with the exact same code used in `next`, with the same result.

**edit**

Heh, just looked at it in IE, same issue but the buttons are reversed, the `prev` button renders fine but the `next` button prints the reference. Odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact problem and it drove me nuts.

The below appears to work fine:

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('&laquo; ', array('escape'=>false), '&laquo; ', array('escape'=>false, 'class' => 'disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator'=>'&nbsp;'));
echo $this->Paginator->next(' &raquo;', array('escape'=>false), ' &raquo;', array('escape'=>false, 'class' => 'disabled'));
```

I *believe* this behaviour is intended, but it doesn't seem very logical to me at least - let me know how you get on.

I'm not sure on the specifics, but both `next` and `prev` have a third parameter. In your code you have `null` - in my code I have the `&raquo;` - and my version displays fine.

> string $disabledTitle optional NULL Title when the link is disabled.

NB in my app; my `class="disabled"` hid the `&raquo` from view - you might not want this.

Answer (score 0):

The PaginatorComponent is expecting to receive 4 inputs:

1. Title when button is active;
2. Options when is active;
3. Title when button is disabled;
4. Options when is disabled;

You can put the 3rd element to null and it will take the title from when the button is active but you still need to specify it's options. So, you just need to add the option to disable escape on disabled button options, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->prev("&lsaquo;", array('escape' => false), null, array('class' => 'pagination_disabled', 'escape' => false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '')); ?>    
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next("&rsaquo;", array('escape' => false), null, array('class' => 'pagination_disabled','escape' => false)); ?>
```